# Why is $f(x,y) = 1/(x^2 + y^2 + 1)$ undefined for the y axis?

Tags: functions

I was told that $f(x,y) = 1/(x^2 + y^2 + 1)$ is undefined for the y axis. I.e $x=0$

At first this made sense, but wouldn't the function simply be $f(0,y) = 1/( y^2 + 1)$ which the denominator is not 0? And therefore defined??

Comment: The maximal domain of $f$ as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ is $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 2):

You were told incorrectly (or possibly misunderstood). The domain of a rational function is the set of all points where the denominator is nonzero. But $1 + x^2 + y^2$ does not vanish, so the domain of $f$ is the entire plane.

Comment: So to make this function undefined, would I simply have to remove the 1 from the demoninator and then for the y axis, f(x,y) would be undefined?

Answer (score 1):

Since:
 $(x^2 + y^2 + 1) \neq 0, \vee x,y \in \mathbb{R}$
 The function:
 $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{(x^2 + y^2 + 1)}$ is defined for every $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$